# Internal Test Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

It is my first time uploading an apk in google play console and I'm having a problem in Internal Test in Google Play Console. I uploaded an apk file and it says
**Available to internal testers** but when i click the link that google provided first gave me this

[image]

after I clicked **download it on Google Play** it shows

[image]

**I haven't publish it in the production** yet. I don't know what is the problem. Please someone help me on this. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to add testers' email addresses

Comment: @Vishnu I already added testers but it shows that error

Comment: When did you upload the app?

Comment: @Vishnu last night at 10pm. Do I have to wait 48 hours in internal testing?

Comment: Yeah! I think so... Does it show `Pending Publication` or `Being Reviewed` in Play Console?

Comment: @Vishnu it shows `Available to internal testers`. I click the link under `How testers join your test` it shows the error above, also in the dashboard the button `View on google play` it also show not found

Comment: Try waiting for a little more. At least 48 hours. It might be getting reviewed or something...

Comment: @Vishnu it seems like my app is on `Pending Publication`. Why is it not showing in Google play console Website tho it is showing on their mobile app? its weird.

Comment: Yes! The app is more usable than the website!!!

Comment: @Vishnu it is already 48 hours but still my `Pending Publication`

Comment: Please wait. It took more than a week for my first app to get reviewed...

Answer (score 2):

Please check if the internal testers have enable this on their device:

`Google Play` -> `Settings` -> `Play Store version` and tap several times on Play Store Version in order to be `developer enabled`.

Comment: yes the developer mode in play store is already enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the cause my IARC is not yet approved.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this issue:

- You need to check if your internal testers email are included in the internal testers list located in the internal testers tab under testers column.
- After checking, your testers needed to opt-in in the internal testers link found in the bottom page of the internal testers tab under testers column.
- You may check this documentation for further reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en