# Google Play Permission Issue

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions, google-play-console

I found it strange that in Google Play Console under **App Bundle Explorer** in my app permission is different from my android manifest.

**Google Play Console Permission**

```
android.hardware.location, 
android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, 
android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS, 
android.permission.CAMERA, 
android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, 
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS, 
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, 
android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, 
android.permission.VIBRATE, 
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS, 
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE, 
com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE, 
com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Is that normal or do i need to change that somehow might occur a problem?

Comment: Probably those extra dependency comes from library you are using. They will get merge during manifest merger .

Comment: @ADM is that normal? because my internal test link i'm having this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65104158/internal-test-google-play-console?noredirect=1#comment115114178_65104158

Comment: This issue is not related to permission I guess . It's related to testing configuration .

Answer (score 0):

I haved the same problem and I checked that the permissions that appear are merged with my AndroidManifest.xml in the build. These are permissions required by packages that I added to my project. To help check which packages are needed I go to **android > app > build > outputs > logs > manifest-merger-release-report.txt**.

If you think that some permission its not required you can update the **Android Manifest**, for example:

```js
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```